# How can export mysql data in to xml using php

Tags: php, php-5.3, php-5.5, php-5.6

Below code is for export data from mysql table as xml file. I have tried several code but not getting the result. Please check and help me.

**Currently getting result is**

```
8sarathsarathernakulam423432washington9rahulrahulernakulam21212121newyork10aaaa3london11bbbb1newyork12cccc2washington13dddd3london
```

**Code**

```
<?php
require_once "classes/dbconnection-class.php";
if(isset($_POST['export'])){
    header('Content-type: text/xml');
    $xml          = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
    $root_element = "addressbook"; //fruits
    $xml         .= "<$root_element>";
    $query        = "SELECT AB.id, AB.name, AB.firstname, AB.street, AB.zipcode, AB.city_id, CI.city FROM address_book AS AB INNER JOIN city AS CI ON AB.city_id = CI.id";
    $result      = $mysqli->query($query);
    if (!$result) {
        die('Invalid query: ' . $mysqli->error());
    }

    while($result_array = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $xml .= "<address>";
        foreach($result_array as $key => $value)
        {
            //$key holds the table column name
            $xml .= "<$key>";

            //embed the SQL data in a CDATA element to avoid XML entity issues
            $xml .= "<![CDATA[$value]]>";

            //and close the element
            $xml .= "</$key>";
        }

        $xml.="</address>";
    }
    $xml .= "</$root_element>";
    header ("Content-Type:text/xml");
    //header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.xml"');
    echo $xml;
}
?>
```

**Browser shows**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><addressbook><address><id><![CDATA[8]]></id><name><![CDATA[sarath]]></name><firstname><![CDATA[sarath]]></firstname><street><![CDATA[ernakulam]]></street><zipcode><![CDATA[42343]]></zipcode><city_id><![CDATA[2]]></city_id><city><![CDATA[washington]]></city></address><address><id><![CDATA[9]]></id><name><![CDATA[rahul]]></name><firstname><![CDATA[rahul]]></firstname><street><![CDATA[ernakulam]]></street><zipcode><![CDATA[2121212]]></zipcode><city_id><![CDATA[1]]></city_id><city><![CDATA[newyork]]></city></address><address><id><![CDATA[10]]></id><name><![CDATA[a]]></name><firstname><![CDATA[a]]></firstname><street><![CDATA[a]]></street><zipcode><![CDATA[a]]></zipcode><city_id><![CDATA[3]]></city_id><city><![CDATA[london]]></city></address><address><id><![CDATA[11]]></id><name><![CDATA[b]]></name><firstname><![CDATA[b]]></firstname><street><![CDATA[b]]></street><zipcode><![CDATA[b]]></zipcode><city_id><![CDATA[1]]></city_id><city><![CDATA[newyork]]></city></address><address><id><![CDATA[12]]></id><name><![CDATA[c]]></name><firstname><![CDATA[c]]></firstname><street><![CDATA[c]]></street><zipcode><![CDATA[c]]></zipcode><city_id><![CDATA[2]]></city_id><city><![CDATA[washington]]></city></address><address><id><![CDATA[13]]></id><name><![CDATA[d]]></name><firstname><![CDATA[d]]></firstname><street><![CDATA[d]]></street><zipcode><![CDATA[d]]></zipcode><city_id><![CDATA[3]]></city_id><city><![CDATA[london]]></city></address></addressbook>
```

Comment: I have the impression that what you say is the result you get actually is just what is visualized in your browser. Please note that a browser is not capable of visualizing xml as you create it in any meaningful way. Consider taking a look at the source of the document your browser shows or dump your output into a file and look at that.

Comment: @arkascha, Thanks, I have updated my browser result with my question. I checked that but I didn't found issue. I don't know why result is not getting properly.

Comment: OK, that looks much better! Now if you also tell us what exactly is wrong with the result you get we would actually be able to help with your question...

Comment: I don't understand what doesn't work

Comment: The result shown in browser seem right ... how do you get the first result? Or else, how is the browser result wrong?

Comment: Your browser will never show you xml like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><addressbook><address>...` this, it will show only values inside tags, but if you view source the page your will see your full generated xml

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When we are dealing with XML and HTML, the best way to act is **ever** through a parser.
In this particular situation, operating with a parser guarantees a valid XML and a clean, short code.

After defining mySQL query, we init a new `DOMDocument` with version and encoding, then we set his `->formatOutput` to True to print out XML in indented format:

```
$query = "SELECT AB.id, AB.name, AB.firstname, AB.street, AB.zipcode, AB.city_id, CI.city FROM address_book AS AB INNER JOIN city AS CI ON AB.city_id = CI.id";

$dom   = new DOMDocument( '1.0', 'utf-8' );
$dom   ->formatOutput = True;
```

Then, we create the root node and we append it to `DOMDocument`:

```
$root  = $dom->createElement( 'addressbook' );
$dom   ->appendChild( $root );
```

At this point, after executing mySQL query, we perform a `while` loop through each resulting row; for each row, we create an empty node `<address>`, then we perform a `foreach` loop through each row's field. For each field, we create an empty childnode with tag as field key, then we append to childnode the field value as CDATA and the same childnode to `<address>` node; at the end of each `while` loop, each `<address>` node is appended to root node:

```
$result     = $mysqli->query( $query );
while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() )
{
    $node = $dom->createElement( 'address' );
    foreach( $row as $key => $val )
    {
        $child = $dom->createElement( $key );
        $child ->appendChild( $dom->createCDATASection( $val) );
        $node  ->appendChild( $child );
    }
    $root->appendChild( $node );
}
```

Now, your XML is ready.

If you want **save it to a file,** you can do it by:

```
$dom->save( '/Your/File/Path.xml' );
```

Otherwise, if you prefer **send it as XML** you have to use this code:

```
header( 'Content-type: text/xml' );
echo $dom->saveXML();
exit;
```

If you want instead **output it in HTML page,** you can write this code:

```
echo '<pre>';
echo htmlentities( $dom->saveXML() );
echo '</pre>';
```

---

- See more about [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Comment: Somewhere [bobince is smiling at this while riding a pony](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2370483)

Comment: @fusion3k Thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

Go to your phpmyadmin database export and select xml in file format.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$xml .= "<![CDATA[$value]]>";
```

with

```
$xml .= $value;
```

Comment: You're going to have to elaborate on this to avoid downvotes. The OP said he was using `CDATA` to avoid breaking XML compatability

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to have it format it "nicely" in the browser add an:

```
echo "<pre>";
```

before the:

```
echo $xml;
```

Please note this WILL BREAK the XML file, but it will look good in the browser.... if that is what you are after...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use libraries like [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/simplexml) etc. to create XML documents.

```php
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?><{$root_element}></{$root_element}>"); 
while($result_array = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    foreach($result_array as $key => $value)
    {
        $address = $xml->addChild("address");
        //embed the SQL data in a CDATA element to avoid XML entity issues
        $addressFields = $address->addChild('"' . $key . '"', "<![CDATA[$value]]>");

       //No need to close the element
    }
}
Header('Content-type: text/xml');
print($xml->asXML());
```